# MySQL date formatting JavaScript

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker

Have post input via a JavaScript date-picker which is assigned to a variable producing a result like 2015-01-11.

Looking to insert into date field on MySQL.
I have tried many combination `STR_TO_DATE($date_field,'%Y-%m-%d)` and
`date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime(sanatize($_POST['date_field'])))`.

Comment: You will need to post the sample code that provided you no joy and any debug efforts that you tried with console.log in Javascript or var_dump in PHP. That'll help other users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the date value in MySQL:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$date_field', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Otherwise, it will treat `2015-01-11` as subtraction of numbers.